# The converse of Newton's shell theorem

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, symmetry, potential-energy

The shell theorem states that a spherically symmetric body $S$ of mass $m$ has a gravitational field identical to that of a point particle $P$ of mass $m$ located at the center of $S$.

We can ask the converse question: suppose there is a force $F$ between masses $M$ and $m$, separated by a distance $r$ of the form $$F = M m f ( r )$$  such that any spherically symmetric body affects external bodies as if its mass were concentrated at its center. Then what form can the function $f$ take?

According to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem, the general solution is

$$f(r)=a/r^2+br$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

I attempted to demonstrate this. Replacing the gravitational force with the general force $F=Mmf(r)$ in the calculations to prove the shell theorem, I got that for all distances $r \ge R > 0$, $f$ satisfies:

$$\int_{r-R}^{R+r} (r^2-R^2 +s^2) f(s)\ ds = 4r^2Rf(r).$$

We can take the second derivative of both sides with respect to $r$ to get rid of the integral (we'll need to differentiate inside the integral), and we get the following nasty differential equation:

$$2Rrf''(r)+6Rf'(r)=f'(r+R)(r+R)+2f(r+R)-f'(r-R)(r-R)-2f(r-R).$$

I don't think this really helps. We can easily verify that $f=ar^2+br$ is a solution of this equation, so I didn't make any mistakes thus far (note the equation is linear so it suffices to check it for $f=r$ and $f=1/r^2$).

So how can we demonstrate the result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Converse shell theorem for an **exterior** point mass:*
>
> 1. Assume that the force ${\bf F}_{12}$ between two point masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ is collinear with the difference in positions ${\bf r}_{12}:={\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2$, is central, and the magnitude
>    $$|{\bf F}_{12}|=m_1m_2 f(|{\bf r}_{12}|)\tag{*}$$
>    is proportional to both the two point masses. We call the function  $f(|{\bf r}_{12}|)$ the specific force.
> 2. Assume furthermore that the magnitude of the total force between an extended spherically symmetric mass $M$ and an exterior point mass $m$ is of the same form $$|{\bf F}|=mM f(r),\tag{**}$$
>    where $r\equiv |{\bf r}|$ is the distance between $m$ and the center of $M$.
> 3. Then the specific force $f$ is a linear combination of
>
>    - a linear/[Hooke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) force,
>    - an inverse square/[Newtonian gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) force.

*Sketched proof:* Let us use the same notation as the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem). We consider the *outside* of a thin shell, i.e. $r\geq R$.

[image]

Let us for simplicity work in terms of potential energy (rather than force), because it is easier to work with a scalar (rather than a vector) quantity. We may assume that the contribution $dU$ to the potential energy of the mass $m$ and $dM$ with distance $s$ is of the form

$$ dU~=~m~dM~u(s),\tag{1.1}$$

where $s\mapsto u(s)$ is an unknown specific potential. Define for later convenience the [antiderivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative)

$$V(s)~:=~\int^s\! ds^{\prime}~s^{\prime}~ u(s^{\prime}), 
\tag{1.2}$$

so that

$$V^{\prime}(s)~\stackrel{(1.2)}{=}~s~u(s).\tag{1.3}$$

From geometry we have the cosine relation

$$ \cos\theta ~=~\frac{r^2+R^2-s^2}{2rR},\tag{1.4} $$

and therefore

$$dM ~=~ \frac{M}{2}\sin\theta~ d\theta
~=~-\frac{M}{2}~d\cos(\theta)
~\stackrel{(1.4)}{=}~\frac{M}{2}\frac{s~ds}{rR}.\tag{1.5}$$

In the last equality of eq.(1.5) we varied $s$ and $\theta$ while holding $r$ and $R$ fixed. Then we have

$$dU~\stackrel{(1.1)+(1.5)}{=}~\frac{mM}{2}\frac{s~ds}{rR}~u(s)
~\stackrel{(1.3)}{=}~\frac{mM}{2rR}ds~V^{\prime}(s).\tag{1.6}$$

So the total potential energy is

$$U(r,R)~=~\int dU
~\stackrel{(1.6)}{=}~mM\frac{V(r+R)-V(r-R)}{2rR}$$
$$~\stackrel{(1.8)}{=}~\frac{mM}{r}\left(V^{\prime}(r)+ \frac{R^2}{6}V^{\prime\prime\prime}(r)+ {\cal O}(R^5)\right).\tag{1.7}$$

In the last equality of eq. (1.7), we Taylor-expanded the potential

$$V(r\pm R)~=~V(r) \pm RV^{\prime}(r) + \frac{R^2}{2}V^{\prime\prime}(r) \pm \frac{R^3}{6}V^{\prime\prime\prime}(r)+ {\cal O}(R^4). \tag{1.8}$$

Let us now implement the main converse shell assumption: We assume that the potential energy $U(r,R)$ up to an ambiguity in the choice of zero-point energy $U_0(R)$ does not depend on the radius $R$ of the thin shell, i.e. $U(r,R)$ is of the form

$$U(r,R)~=~U_1(r)+U_0(R) .\tag{1.9} $$

We see that the only way that eq. (1.7) could be of the form (1.9) is iff

$$ V^{\prime\prime\prime}(r)~\stackrel{(1.7)+(1.9)}{\propto}~r,\tag{1.10} $$

i.e. $V^{\prime}$ is a 3rd-order polynomial with a missing 2nd-order term:

$$ V^{\prime}(r)~\stackrel{(1.10)}{=}~Ar^3+Br^2+Cr+D\tag{1.11}, \qquad B~=~0. $$

Or in terms of the specific potential

$$ u(r)~\stackrel{(1.3)+(1.11)}{=}~Ar^2+C+\frac{D}{r}\tag{1.12}. $$

Or in terms of the specific force

$$ -f(r)~=~u^{\prime}(r)~\stackrel{(1.12)}{=}~2Ar-\frac{D}{r^2}\tag{1.13}. $$

$\Box$

Comment: Future project: Generalize to $n$ spatial dimensions: $f(r)~=~ a/r^{1-n} +b r $.

Answer (score 3):

This follows from Gauss's law.  The $1/r^2$ part would be for a Gaussian sphere of radius greater the radius if the source, while the $r$ part follows from having a Gaussian sphere with radius inside the source, assuming uniform mass density.

The best way to show this is to start from the differential equation for the *potential* in spherical coordinates assuming spherical symmetry; this would be the Laplace equation outside and the Poisson equation with a constant term on the right inside the source.  Once you have the potential you can get the force through the gradient.

---

Edit.  Start from
\begin{align}
\nabla^2V(r)&=0\, ,\\
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{dV}{dr}\right)&=0\, ,\\
r^2\frac{dV}{dr}&=-a\, ,
\end{align}
for some constant $a$.  This is enough to give you the force as $\sim 1/r^2$ outside the source since $F_r=-\frac{dV}{dr}$.

Inside, you need to find a particular solution to 
$$
\nabla^2V=4\pi G\,\rho_m
$$
where $\rho_m$ is the mass density.  By inspection $dV/dr=4\pi G\rho_m\,r/3$ will work; this entails $F_r=br$ inside the source.  The general solution with $\rho_m\ne 0$ is then the sum of the particular solution and the sum of the homogenous problem.

Comment: I guess I'll have to revisit this answer when I've done some higher level physics because I don't understand why the statement that a spherically symmetric body acts as if all its mass is concentrated at its center is equivalent to the condition you gave with the Laplace and Poisson equations.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou  
The key points are: 1. the spherical symmetry and 2. the potential, which must satisfy $\nabla^2V(r)=4\pi G\rho_m$ as per
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_law_for_gravity#Poisson.27s_equation_and_gravitational_potential (I corrected missing $4\pi G$ factors in my answer).

Comment: how come the total force is the sum when inside and outside follow different equations?

Comment: @rpfphysics the coefficients $a$ and $b$ that appear in the general solution need to be adjusted for particular solutions.

Answer (score 2):

In this answer, we give a proof of the converse shell theorem for an **exterior** point mass summing over **forces** rather than **potentials,** in the spirit of OP's calculation.

*Sketched proof:* We use the same notation as the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) and [my other Phys.SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/318290/2451). We consider the *outside* of a thin shell, i.e. $r\geq R$. Define for later convenience the [antiderivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative)

$$W(s)~:=~-\int^s\! ds^{\prime}~(s^{\prime})^2~ f(s^{\prime}), 
\tag{2.1}$$

so that

$$W^{\prime}(s)~\stackrel{(2.1)}{=}~- s^2~f(s).\tag{2.2}$$

The cosine relation yields

$$ \cos\phi ~=~\frac{s^2+r^2-R^2}{2sr}.\tag{2.3} $$

The radial contribution $dF_r$ to the force on the mass $m$ from the ring $dM$ with distance $s$ is of the form

$$ \begin{align}dF_r~=~& -m~dM~f(s)~\cos\phi\cr
~\stackrel{(1.5)}{=}& -m~\frac{M}{2}\frac{s~ds}{rR}~f(s)~\cos\phi \cr
~\stackrel{(2.3)}{=}&-\frac{mM}{4r^2R}~ds~f(s)~(s^2+r^2-R^2)\cr
~\stackrel{(2.2)}{=}&\frac{mM}{4r^2R}~ds\left[W^{\prime}(s)+(r^2-R^2)u^{\prime}(s)\right].\end{align}\tag{2.4}$$

The total radial force should be independent of $R$:

$$ \begin{align}F_r(r)~=~&\int \! dF_r\cr
~\stackrel{(2.4)}{=}&\frac{mM}{4r^2R}~\int_{r-R}^{r+R} \! ds\left[W^{\prime}(s)+(r^2-R^2)u^{\prime}(s)\right] \cr
~=~&\frac{mM}{4r^2R}\left[W(r\!+\!R)-W(r\!-\!R)+(r^2-R^2)\left(u(r\!+\!R)-u(r\!-\!R)\right)\right] \cr
~=~&\frac{mM}{2r^2}\left[W^{\prime}(r)+\frac{R^2}{6}W^{\prime\prime\prime}(r)+(r^2-R^2)\left(u^{\prime}(r)+\frac{R^2}{6}u^{\prime\prime\prime}(r)\right)+{\cal O}(R^4)\right]\cr
~=~&\frac{mM}{2}\left[\underbrace{r^{-2}W^{\prime}(r)+u^{\prime}(r)}_{=~-2f(r)}+R^2 (\ldots)+{\cal O}(R^4)\right].\end{align} \tag{2.5}$$

Therefore the ellipses $(\ldots)$ in eq. (2.5) must vanish:

$$ \begin{align}0~=~&(\ldots) \cr
~\stackrel{(2.5)}{=}& \frac{W^{\prime\prime\prime}(r)}{6r^2}- \frac{u^{\prime}(r)}{r^2} +\frac{u^{\prime\prime\prime}(r)}{6} \cr
~\stackrel{(2.2)}{=}& -\frac{1}{6r^2}\frac{d^2(r^2f(r))}{dr^2}+ \frac{f(r)}{r^2} -\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(r)}{6} \cr
~=~& \frac{1}{3}\left( \frac{2f(r)}{r^2}-\frac{2f^{\prime}(r)}{r} -f^{\prime\prime}(r)\right)\cr
~=~& -\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{1}{3r^2} \frac{d(r^2f(r))}{dr}\right)\cr
~\stackrel{(2.2)}{=}& \frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{W^{\prime\prime}(r)}{3r^2}\right).\end{align} \tag{2.6}$$

Hence

$$ W^{\prime\prime}(r)~\stackrel{(2.6)}{\propto}~r^2 ,\tag{2.7}$$

so that

$$ W^{\prime}(r)~\stackrel{(2.7)}{=}~\alpha r^3+\beta. \tag{2.8}$$

Or in terms of the specific force

$$ -f(r)~\stackrel{(2.2)}{=}~\frac{W^{\prime}(r)}{r^2}~\stackrel{(2.8)}{=}~\alpha r+\frac{\beta}{r^2}. \tag{2.9}$$
$\Box$

So can we understand this result (2.9) intuitively? Yes:

1. The Coulomb law comes from [Gauss' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem#Derivation_using_Gauss%27s_law).
2. The Hooke's law $\vec{f}(\vec{r})=-k\vec{r}$ works for every extended mass $M$ (not necessarily a spherically symmetric shell) that is invariant under spatial point reflection $\vec{R}\to -\vec{R}$. This follows from linearity: Two antipodes $\vec{f}(\vec{r}\!+\!\vec{R})+\vec{f}(\vec{r}\!-\!\vec{R})=2\vec{f}(\vec{r})$ contribute as much as twice the midpoint(=center).

Answer (score 2):

> *Converse shell theorem for an **interior** point mass:*
>
> 1. Assume that the force ${\bf F}_{12}$ between two point masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ is collinear with the difference in positions ${\bf r}_{12}:={\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2$, is central, and the magnitude
>    $$|{\bf F}_{12}|=m_1m_2 f(|{\bf r}_{12}|)\tag{*}$$
>    is proportional to both the two point masses. We call the function  $f(|{\bf r}_{12}|)$ the specific force.
> 2. Assume furthermore that the total force between an extended spherically symmetric mass $M$ and an interior point mass $m$ vanish.
> 3. Then the specific force $f$ is an inverse square/[Newtonian gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) force.

*Sketched proof:* We use the same notation as the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) and [my other Phys.SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/418801/2451). We consider the *inside* of a thin shell, i.e. $r\leq R$.

The total radial force should be zero:

$$\begin{align} 0~=~&F_r(r)\cr
~=~&\int \! dF_r\cr
\stackrel{(2.4)}{=}&\frac{mM}{4r^2R}~\int_{R-r}^{R+r} \! ds\left[W^{\prime}(s)+(r^2-R^2)u^{\prime}(s)\right]\cr
~=~&\frac{mM}{4r^2R}\left[W(R\!+\!r)-W(R\!-\!r)+(r^2-R^2)\left(u(R\!+\!r)-u(R\!-\!r)\right)\right] \cr
~=~&\frac{mM}{2rR}\left[W^{\prime}(R)+\frac{r^2}{6}W^{\prime\prime\prime}(R)+(r^2-R^2)\left(u^{\prime}(R)+\frac{r^2}{6}u^{\prime\prime\prime}(R)\right)+{\cal O}(r^4)\right]\cr
~=~&\frac{mM}{2rR}\left[\underbrace{W^{\prime}(R)-R^2u^{\prime}(R)}_{=~0}+r^2 (\ldots)+{\cal O}(r^4)\right].\end{align}\tag{3.1}$$

In particular the ellipsis $(\ldots)$ in eq. (3.1) must vanish:

$$\begin{align} 0~=~&(\ldots) \cr
~\stackrel{(3.1)}{=}& \frac{W^{\prime\prime\prime}(R)}{6}+ u^{\prime}(R) -R^2\frac{u^{\prime\prime\prime}(R)}{6} \cr
~\stackrel{(2.2)}{=}&-\frac{1}{6}\frac{d^2(R^2f(R))}{dR^2}-f(R)+R^2\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(R)}{6}\cr
~=~&-\frac{2}{3}\left(2f(R) +Rf^{\prime}(R)\right)\cr
~=~&-\frac{2}{3R}\frac{d(R^2f(R))}{dR}\cr
~\stackrel{(2.2)}{=}&\frac{2W^{\prime\prime}(R)}{3R}.\end{align}\tag{3.2}$$

Hence

$$W^{\prime}(R)~\stackrel{(3.2)}{=}~ {\rm constant},\tag{3.3}$$

and therefore the specific force

$$f(R)~\stackrel{(2.2)}{=}~-\frac{W^{\prime}(R)}{R^2}~\stackrel{(3.3)}{\propto}~ R^{-2}\tag{3.4}$$

is an inverse square force. $\Box$

Comment: Thank you Qmechanic for helping me this far. Now how shall we logically prove that $f(R)=kR^{-2}$ is the only solution, i.e. there are no other solutions. Have you proved in your answer. I do not think so. Am I right or wrong? Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3612111/

Comment: Yes, this answer proves that $f(r)=kr^{-2}$ is the only solution.

Comment: Qmechanic : I think the logic goes as follows: (Please point out if I am wrong) $$\text{Suppose there exists $n$ solutions ${f_1(R)=kR^{-2}, f_2(R), f_3(R),......,f_n(R)}  $}$$ $$\text{You have only proved that $f_1(R)=kR^{-2}$    }$$ $$\text{So next we have to prove $n=1$, i.e. there exists only one $f(R)=kR^{-2}$} $$

Comment: $f(r)=kr^{-2}$ is not an assumption in my proof; it is a conclusion.

Comment: You started from $F=0$ and reached $f(r)=kr^{-2}$. Now what if we start from $F=0$ and by a different approach, we reach $f(r)=f_2(r)$. Then $f(r)=kr^{-2}$ and  $f(r)=f_2(r)$ will both be solutions. How can we eliminate the possibility that we may get $f(r)$ other than $kr^{-2}$?