# How to prove that $u(r)=k \dfrac{1}{r}$ is the only solution for the integral equation $\displaystyle\int_{V'}\rho'\ u(r)\ dV' = constant$?

Tags: electrostatics, mathematical-physics, potential, coulombs-law, differential-equations

Consider a hollow spherical charge with density $\rho'$ **continuously varying** only with respect to distance from the center $O$.

[image]

$V'=$ yellow volume

$k \in \mathbb {R}$

$\forall$ point $P$ **inside** the hollow sphere:

\begin{align}
\vec{E}_P &=\displaystyle\int_{V'}\rho'\ \vec{f}(r)\ dV'\\
&=\int_{V'}\rho'\ [-\nabla u(r)]\ dV'\\ 
&=-\nabla \int_{V'}\rho'\ u(r)\ dV' = 0\\
\implies \int_{V'}\rho'\ u(r)\ dV' &= constant\\
\implies u(r) &=k \dfrac{1}{r}\\
\end{align}

For the proof of last equation, see below:

1. [The converse of Newton's shell theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/318135/the-converse-of-newtons-shell-theorem?answertab=active#tab-top)
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3592927/logically-deducing-inverse-square-law-physics?answertab=votes#tab-top
3. https://www.docdroid.net/Wg59yXo/v-pdf

How shall we prove that $u(r)=k \dfrac{1}{r}$ is the only solution for the integral equation $\displaystyle\int_{V'}\rho'\ u(r)\ dV' = constant$?

The following article is from [wikipedia Shell theorem]. Read the grey highlighted text(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem#Converses_and_generalizations)
[image]

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3612111/11127

Comment: This is proved in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/418809/2451).